# Reuse/ resume Fragment without having to recreate it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I basically have a layout divided into two halves. On my left i have buttons that trigger the various fragments that are displayed in the layout on my right.

[image]

When i click on each button the respective fragment is loaded in the fragment display area. Some of the fragments for example Fragment A and Fragment D display complex data by querying a database or getting data from the internet etc. As long as the app is running this data will not change once it is loaded. My question is can i just revert the fragment to the previous state and display it. To be more clear -> i click Fragment A button, in the Fragment A class all the calculations are done and displayed, then i click Fragment B and fragment B is displayed and then C. Now when i click back on Fragment A button i just want it to load back the data, not redo calculation/connections/db queries.

Code being used :

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (position) {
            case 0:
                newContent = new FragmentA();
                break;
            case 1:
                newContent = new FragmentB();
                break;
            case 2:
                newContent = new FragmentC();
                break;
            case 3:
                    newContent = new FragmentD();
                break;
                case 4:
                newContent = new FragmentE();
                break;
                       default: break;
                  }
                     if (newContent != null){
         mContent = newContent;
         switchFragment(newContent);
        }

}

public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mContent = fragment;
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.replacelayout, fragment)
    .commit();
}
```

---

Fragment Code example

```
 public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container, false);
    }   

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);            


   RUN ASYNTASKS TO CONNECT/QUERYDB AND DIPLAY THE DATA

}
    }
```

---

Don't know how to go about it - using backStack ?? onResume() ?? because i am not sure what function is invoked when the .replace is invoked.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fragment.replace you can use fragment.show and fragment.hide fragmentByTagName. This will keep they're states in memory. It might look something like this.

```
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        //find the fragment by View or Tag
          MyFrag myFrag = (MyFrag)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG);
          fragmentTransaction.hide(myOldFrag);
          fragmentTransaction.show(myNewFrag);
          fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Fragment newContent = null;
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .hide(mContent)
            .commit();

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .show(home)
                .commit();
                mContent = home;
                getSlidingMenu().showContent();
                break;
            case 1:

                if(ifdownexsists == true){
                     getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .show(download)
                        .commit();
                        mContent = download;
                        getSlidingMenu().showContent();}
                else
                {   download = new DownloadFile();
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.replacelayout, download)
                    .commit();   
                    mContent = download;
                    ifdownexsists = true;
                    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                 if(ifexsists == true){
                     getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .show(oldCheckValue)
                        .commit();
                        mContent = oldCheckValue;
                        getSlidingMenu().showContent();}
                else
                {   oldCheckValue = new CheckValues();
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.replacelayout, oldCheckValue)
                    .commit();   
                    mContent = oldCheckValue;
                    ifexsists = true;
                    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
                }
                break;
```

Works like a charm ... even keeps the progress of the progressbars in the background and shows them correctly when the fragment becomes visible again